# Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details

Tags: django, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, github-cli

`Deployment Failed. deployer = GITHUB_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build. Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.`

I am using GitHub cli to deploy my Django app to Azure app service It was working fine until GitHub started to use zip deployment or package deployment then It gives me this error.

I tried to add `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1`in my app configurations and the deployments pass in GitHub without errors but the app doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you check the logs (as the error message suggests)?

Comment: Yes I did when the container trying to start It gives me this manage "for site <site> has exited, failing site start"

Answer (score 0):

- Check the logs in `Azure App Service=>Deployment Center=>Logs` to know error in detail.
- Try adding settings ***SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1*** and ***ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=1*** in `App Service=>Configuration=>New Application Settings(in old Azure portal) (or) App Service=>Environmental variables`.
- If still the issue persists, try deploying with other method like `GitHub Actions`.

---

I deployed a *simple Django web app* to *Azure App Service* using *GitHub Actions.*

**Steps followed:**

- Configure ***Deployment*** during the creation of ***App Service*** in ***Azure portal*** by `Enabling continuous deployment` and select the `GitHub repository and branch of your Django project`.

[image]

- It creates workflow to deploy the project to Azure automatically in ***GitHub***, the deployment status can be tracked in `your repository=>Actions`.

**My Workflow (.yml):**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_87XXXXXX }}
```

**Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I am actually using GitHub Action not cli sorry!! but I tried that, In the beginning every thing work but when the project get bigger in size and it start to use Zip deployment the problem happen, I tried what you mention I also tried to set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1
this allow the action to complete the process but the website doesn't work It can't find the site, this message appear in the log ` for site <site> has exited, failing site start`

Comment: By default, Github actions uses zip deployment to deploy the app to Azure. Can you give your GitHub repo link, I'll try from my end and check what causing the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/Fahad-Almaani/UTASHub.git

Comment: I could deploy the [same project](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/UTASHub/actions/runs/6492740529/job/17634396730) to Azure without any issues. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/Nm5Q697.png).

Comment: I created a new app service and now It works fine thank you for the help :).